# xepersian 21.9 cannot load the font "Psychedelia HM". Is this a bug?

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, xepersian

After upgrading my texlive, xepersian 21.9 can not load the font which
is loaded without any problem by the older version 21.7.

My code is:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{xepersian}
 \settextfont[Scale=1.44]{Amiri}
 \setlatintextfont[Scale=1.44]{Psychedelia HM}
 \pagestyle{empty}
 \begin{document}
  فانت سایکیدلیا اچ‌ام. \lr{Psychedelia HM font.}
 \end{document}
```

and the error I get is:

```
 (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/loadingorder
 -xepersian.def)
 (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/footnote-xep
 ersian.def)
 (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/article-xepe
 rsian.def) (./fontspec-xepersian.def))

 ! Package xepersian Error:  The font "Psychedelia HM" cannot be loaded by                the
 (xepersian)                xepersian package. 

 For immediate help type H <return>.
  ...                                              

 l.5 \pagestyle
               {empty}
 ? h

  Select another font and rerun "xelatex". 

 ?
```

If this is a bug in xepersian 21.9, how can I fix it?

Please note that the file `./fontspec-xepersian.def` is exactly the same as
`c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/fontspec-xepersian.def`
which is one of the xepersian's configuration files. I copied the file
to my working directory to fix the problem, but I couldn't.
The contents of `fontspec-xepersian.def` is as follows:

```
%%
%% This is file `fontspec-xepersian.def',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% xepersian.dtx  (with options: `table,fontspec-xepersian.def')
%% 
%%   __________________________________________________
%%   Copyright (c) 2008--2018  Vafa Khalighi <persian-tex@tug.org>
%% 
%%   It may be distributed and/or modified under the LaTeX Project Public License,
%%   version 1.3c or higher (your choice). The latest version of
%%   this license is at: http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% 
%%   This work is “author-maintained” (as per LPPL maintenance status)
%%   by Vafa Khalighi.
%% 
%% 
%% \CheckSum{10904}
%% \CharacterTable
%%  {Upper-case    \A\B\C\D\E\F\G\H\I\J\K\L\M\N\O\P\Q\R\S\T\U\V\W\X\Y\Z
%%   Lower-case    \a\b\c\d\e\f\g\h\i\j\k\l\m\n\o\p\q\r\s\t\u\v\w\x\y\z
%%   Digits        \0\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8\9
%%   Exclamation   \!     Double quote  \"     Hash (number) \#
%%   Dollar        \$     Percent       \%     Ampersand     \&
%%   Acute accent  \'     Left paren    \(     Right paren   \)
%%   Asterisk      \*     Plus          \+     Comma         \,
%%   Minus         \-     Point         \.     Solidus       \/
%%   Colon         \:     Semicolon     \;     Less than     \<
%%   Equals        \=     Greater than  \>     Question mark \?
%%   Commercial at \@     Left bracket  \[     Backslash     \\
%%   Right bracket \]     Circumflex    \^     Underscore    \_
%%   Grave accent  \`     Left brace    \{     Vertical bar  \|
%%   Right brace   \}     Tilde         \~}
%%
\ProvidesFile{fontspec-xepersian.def}[2018/11/26 v0.2 fontspec changes]
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \__xepersian_error:nx    { \msg_error:nnx    {xepersian} }
\char_set_catcode_space:n {32}
\cs_new:Nn \__xepersian_msg_new:nnnn
  { \msg_new:nnxx {#1} {#2} { \tl_trim_spaces:n {#3} } { \tl_trim_spaces:n {#4} } }
\__xepersian_msg_new:nnnn {xepersian} {font-cannot-be-loaded}
 {
  The font "#1" cannot be loaded by the xepersian package.
 }
 {
  Select another font and rerun "xelatex".
 }
\char_set_catcode_ignore:n {32}
\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \__xepersian_font_if_cannot_be_loaded:Nn {p,TF,T,F}
  {
    \str_if_in:NnTF { #1 } { #2 }
    {
      \prg_return_true:
    }
    {
      \prg_return_false:
    }
  }
\cs_undefine:N \__fontspec_load_font:
\cs_new:Nn \__fontspec_load_font:
 {
  \__fontspec_primitive_font_set:Nnn \l_fontspec_font
     { \__fontspec_construct_font_call:nn { \l__fontspec_fontname_up_tl } {} } {\f@size pt}
  \__fontspec_primitive_font_if_null:NT \l_fontspec_font { \__fontspec_error:nx {font-not-found} {\l__fontspec_fontname_up_tl} }
  \__xepersian_font_if_cannot_be_loaded:NnT \l__fontspec_fontname_up_tl { HM }
  {
    \__xepersian_error:nx {font-cannot-be-loaded} {\l__fontspec_fontname_up_tl}
    \cs_gset_eq:NN \l__fontspec_fontname_up_tl \tex_nullfont:D
  }
  \__fontspec_set_font_type:N \l_fontspec_font
  \__fontspec_primitive_font_gset:Nnn \l_fontspec_font
     { \__fontspec_construct_font_call:nn { \l__fontspec_fontname_up_tl } {} } {\f@size pt}
  \l_fontspec_font % this is necessary for LuaLaTeX to check the scripts properly
 }
\cs_undefine:N \__fontspec_load_fontname:n
\cs_new:Nn \__fontspec_load_fontname:n
 {
    \__fontspec_load_external_fontoptions:Nn \l_fontspec_fontname_tl {#1}
    \prop_get:NVNF \g__fontspec_fontopts_prop \l_fontspec_fontname_tl \l__fontspec_fontopts_clist
     { \clist_clear:N \l__fontspec_fontopts_clist }
    \keys_set_groups:nnV {fontspec/fontname} {getfontname} \l__fontspec_fontopts_clist
    \__fontspec_primitive_font_set:Nnn \l_fontspec_font { \__fontspec_construct_font_call:nn {\l_fontspec_fontname_tl} {} } {\f@size pt}
    \__fontspec_primitive_font_if_null:NT \l_fontspec_font { \__fontspec_error:nx {font-not-found} {#1} }
  \__xepersian_font_if_cannot_be_loaded:NnT #1 { HM }
  {
    \__xepersian_error:nx {font-cannot-be-loaded} {#1}
    \cs_gset_eq:NN \l_fontspec_font \tex_nullfont:D
  }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `fontspec-xepersian.def'.
```

Comment: note that you have a local configuration file `./fontspec-xepersian.def` so you should show the contents of that, and also say where that ffont comes from, otherwise no one can run your test

Comment: also you tagged this pdftex, but you are presumably using xetex

Comment: Do you have also problems with fonts available in texlive? E.g. TeX Gyre Heros?

Comment: @David Carlisle, I edited both the tags and the question. I also added
the contents of the file ./fontspec-xepersian.def.
The font "Psychedelia HM" is in the systems' font directory and as I
said my code works fine with xepersian-21.7 but fails with
xepersian-21.9.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer, I don't have any problem with fonts in texlive.
This is the first time that I get such an error.

Comment: From the answer you can see that the author of xepersian deliberatly changed internal commands of fontspec to prevent the font to get loaded.

Comment: try `\usepackage[fontsloadable]{xepersian}`

Comment: @TishaShusho It isn't an ideal situation but that is the current situation (it would not be unreasonable to make a local copy of the package  that defaulted that option)

Comment: You can create an empty file called `fontspec-xepersian.def` in your search path to shadow the original file.

Comment: @David Carlisle, As Vafa Khalighi indirectly accused me of being a terrorist, I thought you would never help me to solve my problem even if you knew the solution. The problem with this solution is that if one has many files which contain \usepackage{xepersian} he/she has to modify all of them.

Comment: Thank you all for your invaluable comments and suggestions that helped me solve the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately the package explicitly prevents loading fonts with names that contain the string `HM`

You can use

```
\usepackage[fontsloadable]{xepersian}
```

to disable this or it would not be unreasonable to make a local copy of the package and replace the two instances of `HM` by anything else, eg `ZZZZZ` to disable that feature.

Comment: Thanks, as you said in your previous comment, setting `fontsloadable=true` in `xepersion.sty` works fine too.

Comment: To reject all of the fonts that contain a particular string in their name is the most irresponsible design decision I have ever seen (for whatever reason the xepersian team decided to do that)

Comment: @nima I'm only the messenger.. (but yes, I wouldn't disagree)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes of course :) You don't expect developers in charge of software with such a large user base to make these kinds of unprofessional decisions. It took me two days to find your solution because I didn't even think the problem would be something like this.

Comment: @nima note there isn't a team: it's a one man development

Comment: The problem seems to be fixed in xepersian 22.8. A huge thanks to David.

Comment: They did it again in version 24. Now if you use a font with HM in it's name it won't throw an error but will distort the letters in the output. This is extremely childish and unprofessional.

Comment: @nima I just tried in texlive 2022 and 2023 and [got this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsYQF.png) which looks OK?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, this seems OK. Maybe they check the font's full name. If you use any of the HM or XB Persian font series, the output is distorted. Renaming the exact same fonts, fixes the problem.

Comment: @nima you mean you do not have a problem with the example here either?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, Psychedelia HM works fine.

Comment: [This is what happens.](https://ibb.co/NTCwppJ)

Comment: @nima what font is that?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It's "HM FMitra".

Comment: @nima `No results found for "hm fmitra" font.` I suggest you make a real example and post as a new question referencing this and a source for any needed fonts

Comment: @DavidCarlisle [These](https://file.io/uGizmysJlc0E) are two fonts from HM and XB series. I believe that the xepersian programmer has some sort of a quarrel with the authors of these fonts. And these are popular fonts.

Comment: @nima no sorry I'm not prepared to download font software from an unknown source.

Comment: But see https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xepersian-hm

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This problem is not related to xepersian-hm, because just renaming the fonts fixes the issue. [Here](https://bitbucket.org/dma8hm1334/persian-hm-ftx-3.8/src/master/) is the HM series source, and [here](http://wiki.irmug.com/index.php/X_Series_2) is the XB series.

Comment: @nima that package page links to the fonts, and also does or did remove the restrction. So it is exactly related. But f you want further testing you ask a new question which should provide an example. I can't read the script so would struggle to reproduce [your example](https://ibb.co/NTCwppJ)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I created a new question with context [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/676693/133789).