# xepersian problem with HM fonts

Tags: fonts, xepersian

Back in 2018 xepersian started throwing random errors if you used fonts with a specific string in their name ("HM") and this caused a lot of headache for the users of [these fonts](https://bitbucket.org/dma8hm1334/). This issue was discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462292/133789).

It turned out that the xepersian developer had decided to do this as a result of a quarrel between him and the authors of those fonts, and he had to fix it in the next version.

In texlive 2022, if these fonts are used there are no errors, but the output will be distorted (this seems to be the case for [XB](http://wiki.irmug.com/index.php/X_Series_2) fonts too). Just renaming the font fixes this issue.

Here I'm using two fonts: **HM FMitra** and **RENAMED Mitra** which is the exact same font that I have renamed.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[Kashida]{xepersian}
\settextfont{HM FMitra} 
\def\SampleText{متن آزمایشی}
\begin{document}
\SampleText 
\settextfont{RENAMED Mitra}
\SampleText 
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Am I missing something or the xepersian developer is doing this deliberately again?

Comment: well a font can not be "exactly the same" if you renamed it so that it can be found under another name. I see nothing suspicious in the code, and your difference looks to me as kashida is the problem, if I use `\usepackage[Kashida=true]{xepersian-hm}` as David already suggested to you it seems to work. Beside this, you could try babel + lualatex instead: https://latex3.github.io/babel/guides/locale-arabic.html

Comment: You're absolutely right. I didn't suspect a "kashida" problem, because renaming fixed it. Probably just saving the font changes something. And thanks for the babel + lualatex suggestion.

Comment: did you really access it as `RENAMED Mitra` if you don't use a `.ttf` extension as in my answer it will use the internal font name, which is not changed by copying the fil? Also your output shows two lines but your input only has one paragraph.

Comment: I didn't copy the font file, I opened it in a font editor, changed it's properties and saved it as a new file. New lines were deleted by mistake when I copied the code here. Anyway, as you suggested using xepersian-hm fixed the problem in this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no special cases for HM as there were in some early versions, and the same output for a renamed font

[image: this]

The `xepersian-hm`package loads `xepersian` then adds some extensions including better support for these fonts

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[Kashida=True]{xepersian-hm}
\settextfont{HM_FMitra.ttf} 
\def\SampleText{متن آزمایشی}
\begin{document}

\SampleText 

\settextfont{aaa.ttf}% renamed font
\SampleText 
\end{document}
```